# Spark LDA model prediction on new documents

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib, lda

I am using Spark MLlib to fetch out topic from the documents. I have run below line and got a LDAModel.

```
LDAModel ldaModel = new LDA().setK(4).run(corpus);
```

Now I have another document and want to check what all topics it has. How can that be done using the same ldaModel I generated. The methods available in LDAModel/DistributedLDAModel class do not have any method for prediction.

Do I need to retrain it once again on all documents?

**Note** : I have skipped code here as I am having problem understadning API implementation. I can include if required.

Thanks.

Comment: I am using Java and i did it as follows : DistributedLDAModel sameModel = DistributedLDAModel.load(jsc.sc(),
    model_location);
  Vector document= //your doc vector
  Vector preditedTopic = sameModel.toLocal().topicDistribution(document);

Comment: which spark version of your model@Amit Kumar